# Discretización en Rstudio. Duda de curso de iniciación

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy en pleno curso de iniciación a Rstudio y me he quedado clavado en una de las últimas preguntas del trabajo. El anunciado me pide lo siguiente:

"*Añade una columna al conjunto de datos denominada “Tramos” que contenga los valores: {“Alto”, “Bajo”, “Medio”}. La asignación del valor dependerá de la variable DEBTMEAN. Para ello, se divide el rango de valores de DEBTMEAN en 3 intervalos del mismo tamaño. A continuación, se asigna:

Bajo: intervalo de los valores más bajos.
Medio: intervalo de los valores intermedios.
Alto: intervalo de los valores más altos.

El proceso inherente que se realiza es una discretización de DEBTMEAN por intervalos del mismo tamaño. (Nota: el número de observaciones en cada intervalo será diferente)*"

La variable DEBTMEAN es una variable numérica continua que se refiere a la media de deuda acumulada por los alumnos estadounidenses al encarar una carrera. Os adjunto la muestra:

"*# $ DEBTMEAN: int  37194 33085 36482...*"

Entiendo que debería tirar de condicionantes (ifelse) pero no logro el resultado requerido y sólo estropeo la base de datos. ¿Podéis echarme una mano como mínimo aclarándome por donde debería tirar para resolver esto?

Muchas gracias por la atención.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es algo que nos ha pasado a todos

Utiliza la función `cut` del kernel base

Por ejemplo

```
set.seed(0)
data <- iris[, 1:2] # dummie data.frame
data$DEBTMEAN <- runif(dim(data)[1], 10**5, 10**6)# variable a 'cortar'

# ahora haces los cortes
data$DEBTMEAN.cortes <- cut(data$DEBTMEAN,
                            breaks = seq(min(data$DEBTMEAN), 
                                         max(data$DEBTMEAN), 
                                             length=4), include.lowest = TRUE, 
                            labels = c("Bajo", "Medio", "Alto") )
table(data$DEBTMEAN.cortes)
```

Gracias por el comentario @Patricio Moracho

Comment: Cuidado! deberías agregar al `cut()` el parámetro `include.lowest =  TRUE`, por que por defecto el corte es por valores mayores, sino, el valor mínimo lo va a dejar afuera. O también, es más sencillo hacer : `cut(data$DEBTMEAN, breaks = 3, labels = c("Bajo", "Medio", "Alto"))`. Saludos